# Django REST framework reverse relationship object instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say that we have models like below

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    """Stores a single movie entry."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)


class Watchlist(models.Model):
    """Stores a user watchlist."""

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='watchlist',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name='watchlist',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializer

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for a custom user model with related user action."""

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='customuser-detail', lookup_field='username')

    watchlist = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True, view_name='watchlist-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'watchlist')
```

and the view:

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    list:
    Return a list of all the existing users.

    retrieve:
    Return the given user with user's watchlist.  

    """

    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    permissions = (IsAdminOrReadOnly)
    lookup_field = 'username'
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```

That all will give us a user and hyperlinked filed to the particular watchlist.

```
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/John/",
    "username": "John",
    "favorites": [
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/watchlist/2/",
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/watchlist/1/"
    ]
},
```

but instead of that I would like to get a particular movie instance like that.

```
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/John/",
    "username": "John",
    "favorites": [
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/movies/33/",
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/movies/12/"
    ]
},
```

so my question is how can I achieve that? I tried with hyperlinkedrelatedfield but nothing seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) along with [reverse](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/#reverse).

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for a custom user model with related user action."""

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='customuser-detail', lookup_field='username')

    favorites = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_favorites(self, obj):
        movie_urls = [
            reverse("movie-view", args=[watchlist.movie.id], request=self.context['request'])
            for watchlist in obj.watchlist.all()
        ]
        return movie_urls

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'favorites')
```

Comment: Thanks! I tweak that a little bit, so for args=[movie.movie.id] then request=self.context['request'] and obj.watchlist.all(). Please update your answer and I will accept it!